# Where is intel-ucode

Tags: repository, intel

According to the ArchLinux wiki [intel microcode](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/microcode), I need the package **intel-ucode** in order to install Intel microcode updates.  I'm running Kubuntu 14.10 (Trusty Tahr).  I want the deb package itself rather than an automated installation of it.   Where can I get it?

Comment: 14.10 is Utopic Unicorn. Trusty Tahr is 14.04.

Comment: I guess I'm running Utopic, then.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the package you're looking for is `intel-microcode`.

```
sudo apt-get install intel-microcode
```

Or grab it from http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/intel-microcode.

Comment: It has been updated, even for Trusty to https.  https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/iucode-tool